# ASP.NET MVC 3 JQuery Scripts being lost

Tags: jquery

(Apologies in advance for the long post, but at my wits end)..

I'm getting a weird problem with jquery scripts being "lost", for want of a better word, within my MVC 3 application.

Within my app, I have the following _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</head>
<body>

    <div class="page">

        <div id = "sidebar"> 
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Sidebar"); }               
        </div>

        <div id="main">            
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <div id="validationresults">
            <div id="validationresultsinner"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Sidebar itself is a partial view that contains a couple of Ajax.ActionLinks which load a parent view into the "main" area of my _Layout.cshtml..

```
<ul>
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Section 1", "WizardParentView", "Section1",null, new AjaxOptions() 
    { UpdateTargetId = "main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { id = "sect2" })</li>
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Section 2", "WizardParentView", "Section2", null, new AjaxOptions() 
    { UpdateTargetId = "main", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { id = "sect2" })</li>
</ul>
```

This WizardParentView itself contains an Ajax.Begin form that is used in conjunction with the MVCWizard.Wizard from NuGet, to host a selection of pages that a user can navigate through (e.g. wizard-type pages)

e.g.

```
@model MyDataModel

@{    
    FormWizardManager<MyDataModel> wm = (FormWizardManager<MyDataModel>)Session["TheSection"];
    Layout = "";    
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("WizardParentView", "Section1", new AjaxOptions() {
UpdateTargetId= "wizard", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    <div id="wizard">
    @Html.WizardHeader(wm, true)
    @{Html.RenderAction(wm.CurrentPage.PagePartialView);}
    @Html.WizardFooter(wm, "Next Page " + (wm.Index + 1), "Previous Page" + (wm.Index - 1), "Save this Section")      
    </div>
}

@Content.Script("jquery.validate.js", Url)
@Content.Script("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", Url)
@Content.Script("UIHelpers.Section1.js", Url)
```

I also have some required functionality to modify the text of items in the sidebar to permenantly reflect the status of the users' progress through the wizard.  This text modification is achieved by another bit of JQuery elsewhere that executes on postback (when server side validation is called).  As you can see, to stop the original sidebar partial simply reloading when a sidebar link is again clicked (after it may have been modified), I have also had to clear out the Layout when the WizardParentView loads.

The thing is, when I run this in a dev environment (IE9 with either IIS7 Express or the Visual Studio 2010 Web Development Server), all of the page loading and functionality that requires JQuery or JQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax works fine

However, running the same website under full II7 or II6 (see below) I find that the core scripts and all dependant functionality load and work ok for the first 2 page navigation attempts, but on the third (e.g. Third press of "Next"), the JQuery scripts are definitely no longer there.. meaning my partial view loads into the full web page and any jquery functionality within the view ceases to work.

Further confusion reigns as follows:

**Working**
JQuery 1.5.1 IE9, IIS7 Express, Visual Studio Web Development Server

**Broken**
JQuery 1.5.1 IE9, IIS6, IIS7, IIS7 Express
JQuery 1.5.1 Chrome/Firefox, IIS6, IIS7, II7 Express, Visual Studio Web Development Server
JQuery 1.8.1 IE9, IIS6, IIS7, IIS7 Express, Visual Studio Web Development Server

I would think that clearing the Layout even on the first load of WizardParentView, would wipe out the JQuery scripts I loaded in the _Layout, but the fact that JQuery based functionality still works after 2-3 navigation attempts and then dies, is what's odd.. not to mention that the app functionality works perfectly in at least one of the configurations above (shouldn't the JQuery scripts would be getting wiped out in all scenarios? Or is some kind of weird caching going on with one particular combination of browser, JQuery version and web server?.. sorry, am at a bit of a loss to describe it better.. and apologies for the confusing explanation (in my own head I can describe the problem clearly) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried changing

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so that it can properly map the server path to those files via relative paths?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think I found one of the answers at the weekend.  Basically there was a problem with the markup of my site.. due to my inexperience I had been nesting forms (which I discovered was a no-no) and this was causing the core jquery scripts loaded in my layout to get knocked out as it were..I've since re-designed my site markup and have been testing with Chrome which is much less forgiving with these kind of design issues..

Comment: Unfortunately, I seem to have an issue when trying to upgrade to using JQuery 1.8.1 with the same website.  JQuery scripts to show/hide features stop working a few pages in, whereas they work fine with 1.5.1 (same combination of browsers/web servers)